# How to setup OHIF on windows

Tags: reactjs, ohif

Please what is the correct way to have this Running

i am trying to install this and get it running on windows using this  [documentation](https://docs.ohif.org/).
i have installed Meteor , and then navigated to the folder and typed meteor, as talked about from [here](https://docs.ohif.org/history/v1/essentials/installation.html) and [here](https://kkpradeeban.blogspot.com/2018/10/installing-standalone-viewer-of-ohif.html)

I am getting this as Error

```
run: You're not in a Meteor project directory.

To create a new Meteor project:
  meteor create <project name>
For example:
  meteor create myapp

For more help, see 'meteor --help'.
```

Please what am I not doing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use OHIF I suggest you upgrade to Version 3.
The setup is easier (with good documentation) and the code is more tidy: https://github.com/OHIF/Viewers

I would also suggest to use docker.

This project helped me a lot setting up my instance: https://github.com/trypag/ohif-orthanc-postgres-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml